# Why are my mutable arrays and table views behaving unexpectedly?

Tags: uitableview, ios6, nsmutablearray, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm building a sign-in app. It has two table views. One lists people who have visited before (existingNames), and one lists the current people signed in (names).

At certain points in my code the only mutable array that does not crash the program when accessed is names.

names and existingNames seems to somehow be reversed as well. When I try to remove from names, the program crashes. When I remove from existingNames, the changes are reflected in tableView2, but tableView2 is supposed to be associated with names.

In the app's current state everything is "working" except for accessing any company arrays. I put quotes around working because of the names and existingNames being used backwards.

Any insight into what might be causing the problem would be much appreciated!

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
    UITableView *tableView;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *companyField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *names;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *companies;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *existingNames;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *existingCompanies;

- (IBAction)add:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addExisting:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)remove:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView2;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface ViewController () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize nameField;
@synthesize companyField;
@synthesize names;
@synthesize companies;
@synthesize existingNames;
@synthesize existingCompanies;
@synthesize tableView1 = _tableView1;
@synthesize tableView2 = _tableView2;

int rowNumber1;
int rowNumber2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.companies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.existingNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.existingCompanies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView1){
        return [existingNames count];
    }
    else if (tableView == self.tableView2){
        return [names count];
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (tableView == self.tableView1){
        cell = [_tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    else if (tableView == self.tableView2){
        cell = [_tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.tableView1){
        cell.textLabel.text = [existingNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if (tableView == self.tableView2){
        cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (tableView == self.tableView1){
        rowNumber1 = indexPath.row;
    }
    else if (tableView == self.tableView2){
        rowNumber2 = indexPath.row;
    }
}

- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    BOOL exists = [existingNames containsObject:nameField.text];

    if(exists == FALSE){
        [names addObject:nameField.text];
        [companies addObject:companyField.text];
        [existingNames addObject:nameField.text];
        [existingCompanies addObject:companyField.text];
    }
    else{
        [names addObject:nameField.text];
        [companies addObject:companyField.text];
    }

    [_tableView1 reloadData];
    [_tableView2 reloadData];

    nameField.text=@"";
    companyField.text=@"";
}

- (IBAction)addExisting:(id)sender {
    [existingNames addObject:[names objectAtIndex:rowNumber1]];
    //[companies addObject:[existingCompanies objectAtIndex:rowNumber]];

    [_tableView2 reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)remove:(id)sender {
    [existingNames removeObjectAtIndex:rowNumber2];
    [existingCompanies removeObjectAtIndex:rowNumber2];

    [_tableView2 reloadData];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following methods are part of the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols

```
tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

and will be called by your table view assuming you've property assigned the table view's `delegate` and `dataSource` properties. These methods, however,

```
tableView2:numberOfRowsInSection:
tableView2:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
tableView2:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

are not part of the protocol and won't ever get called by the table view. It looks like you may be confusing your property names, e.g. `tableView`, with with the protocol method names, e.g. `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. What you need to do is:

1. If you haven't already done so, set your view controller as the `delegate` and `dataSource` for both your `tableView` and `tableView2`.
2. In each of the data source and delegate methods that you need to implement, handle the cases for both tables.

For example, your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method would look like:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        return [existingNames count];
    }

    else if (tableView == self.tableView2) {
        return [names count];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have set the datasource and delegate for both table views already.
Thanks in your help in understanding with the tableview docs, they're really a lot to take in! I'll work on it and let you know if anything improves.

Comment: I've been at this for awhile now and I've got the program running, only now the table views are not being populated. I'm posting my new code. I'm assuming it has something to do with the tableview methods. I am receiving a warning every time I reference tableView inside those methods "local declaration of tableView hides instance variable". I have tried other methods to remove this warning, but nothing else has worked.

Comment: Ahh, I got rid of it by adding _ to the method declaration (i.e. - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section). My table views are currently still not being populated though. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming it now has to do with when I call tableView and _tableView in these methods. I'm having trouble understanding when to use which.

Comment: In your interface, you've defined a variable "tableView" and a property "tableView". But in your implementation, you're synthesizing and referencing "tableView1" It seems you're not being consistent with what you're variables. I would suggest a) delete the "tableView" variable definition, b) rename the property from "tableView" to "tableView1", c) undo "adding _ to the method declaration", and d) see how things look. You can put log statements or breakpoints in your delegate methods to make sure they're getting called, verify your arrays, are populated, etc.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I renamed tableView to tableView1 in the interface as well. I forgot to reflect all my changes in the edit, I'll fix it now. I still have the warnings without the _ (why?) and the tableViews are still not being populated. I've already confirmed the NSMutableArrays to contain the correct data.

Comment: Updated. Only change from before was removing _ from the tableView methods.

Comment: Ah, actually my tableView2 is now being populated. I'm going to try to get both going. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Aaaaand my tableView1 somehow was disconnected. 100% working now! From the initial changes you suggested and adding in the rest of the mutable array initialization seemed to do it. Thanks again.